# Passing a string into a method by reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

**Edit:** Sorry guys I forgot to mention that I can't change plugins.js. It is used by many other applications.

I'm trying to pass the `responseName` parameter into the the jQuery click handler as a reference. However it is being passed as a value.

In my callback function, I change `time.ref` to `'b'`, yet when it gets sent back to the server in `sendResponse()` it is still sending `'a'`. How do I fix this?

**Plugins.js**

```
Whispir.plugins.customResponseRules =  {

    attachResponse: function(selector, responseName, callback){

        $(selector).on('click', function(){

            if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback();
            }

            sendResponse({
                textPrompt: responseName, 
                name: responseName
            });

        });


    }

}
```

**Main code**

```
var time = {ref: 'a'};

$(document).ready(function() {


    Whispir.plugins.customResponseRules.attachResponse(
            '#ok-button',
            time.ref,
            function(){
                time.ref = 'b';
            }
    );


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your actual issue is that you're changing the original object in your callback, but what is being sent to the server is what is passed to the function.  Once you've changed the original object, those are no longer the same.

Strings are immutable in javascript and they are actually always passed by reference.

But, because they are immutable you can't change that particular string (all changes to a string, create a new string) so if what you want to do is to change a string that is passed in, then you need to embed the string as a property of an object and pass that object.

---

So, in your particular code, you can pass the `time` object instead of the `time.ref` string.  That way you can change `time.ref` to whatever you want from within the function and as long as you get the data from `time.ref` before sending to the server, you will always have the latest data:

```
Whispir.plugins.customResponseRules =  {

    attachResponse: function(selector, responseObj, callback){
        $(selector).on('click', function(){
            if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback();
            }

            sendResponse({
                textPrompt: responseObj.ref, 
                name: responseObj.ref
            });
        });
    }
}

var time = {ref: 'a'};

$(document).ready(function() {
    Whispir.plugins.customResponseRules.attachResponse(
            '#ok-button',
            time,
            function(){
                time.ref = 'b';
            }
    );
});
```

---

Now, the OP has informed us that the plugin code can't be changed in anyway.

If you can't modify the plugin, then, you can't do it. The plug-in is sending what you passed to it as an argument and you can't change that argument from outside the plug-in. The string argument in a private scope so if you can't change the code inside that scope, then you can't change it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that plugins.js can't be changed.

Comment: @Rich - If you can't modify the plugin, then, you can't do it.  The plug-in is sending what you passed to it as an argument and you can't change that argument from outside the plug-in.  It's in a private scope so if you can't change the code inside that scope, then you can't change it.  The only way to do a "live" reference like you might have in another language is to put the string inside an object and pass the object, but since you can't change the plug-in, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, strings are immutable and *always* passed by reference.

**What does this mean?**

This means strings *cannot* be changed once initialized. You can replace the string with a new string, but you cannot "change the value pointed to by the reference" when you pass in a string to a function.

There are some great answers here already, but I'll provide you with a conceptual answer that can be applied elsewhere.

```
var myObject = { myString : "Hello, World!" }

function changeStr(str) {
    str = "Goodbye, World!";
}
function changeObj(obj) {
    obj.myString = "Goodbye, World!";
}

changeStr(myObject.myString);
alert(myObject.myString); // will alert "Hello, World!"

changeObj(myObject);
alert(myObject.myString); // will alert "Goodbye, World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `time` and access `time.ref` instead of `responseName` in `sendResponse`

**You need to pass an object if it has to be a Pass by reference**

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that plugins.js can't be changed.